# Using HTML5's input form attribute in JSF

Tags: jsf

HTML5 introduced a new `form` attribute, so that it's possible to, for example, have a submit button that's outside of the actual `<form>`, like this:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>

<input type="submit" form="myform" />
```

How can I specify the form target in a JSF `h:commandButton`?

My requirement is to submit the JSF `<h:form>` with a button that's outside the form tag - preferably not using AJAX.

I'm using JSF 2.3.

Comment: Q: Is this actually a "requirement"?  Isn't it just an "implementation detail"?  Can't you just do whatever's easiest in JSF, provided a) the form exists, and b) it has a "submit" button?

Comment: @paulsm4 I meant implementation requirement, not business requirement. It makes using the Bootstrap feature neater and is also of general interest about JSF.